# A book on the parallels between styles in music, theater, architecture, visual arts,

Tags: classical-music, reference-request

I have been looking into different periods in music history (medieval, renaissance, baroque, classic, romantic, 20th century, modern). I am now looking for a book that similarly covers a long period of history (1800s-2000s at the minimum, covering the western world) but with a broader scope; that is, not only how music evolved over the years, but also how, say, architecture, design, visual arts, poetry, etc. evolved over the same years, and preferably there is some focus on the common grounds (e.g., societal? political? philosophical?) of the different/similar evolutions across those disciplines.

Comment: This is, broadly, *Humanities*. Look for terms like "interdisciplinary humanities survey". They do exist, not all are easy reading. I was assigned some in art school, one specifically about Vienna. Interesting stuff, but no way I can recall the titles from 30+ years ago

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a book covering this. Some time ago I found CD booklets attempting to cover other aspects of art and politics happening at the same time as the recorded compositions.

---

I could only find the label **Teldec** providing such information in the 1990 years, see an example here, taken from "Vivaldi Il proteo: double and triple concertos":
[image: Teldec example booklet]